# Reuse IT Statement in Webdriverio IO with different parameters

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium-webdriver, webdriver-io

I'm running an automated test suite of front end website tests using WebdriverIO v7, Selenium, NodeJS in JavaScript.

My current setup is i have 5 different 'login' test cases (one for each customer type), but anytime the website is updated, i need to update the login steps 5 times, for each scenario.

Ideally I would like 1 main login test case that can be re-run 5 times, just changing the 'username' parameter.

Does anyone know if this is possible?

I have looked online and not found a lot of info on referencing test cases from different files / re-run the same test using different variables. All info on retrying i've found is re. failing test cases.

Comment: Yes it is possible. Check out "Data provider selenium"